# "chrome.debugger" conflict with "showDevTools(true)" in NW.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webview, nwjs

I creating a desktop App base on NW.js

And i use the Webview tag simulated a touch device such as Iphone screen.

```
chrome.debugger.attach(debuggee, '1.1', () =>{
                chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggee, 'Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled',{
                  enabled: true,
                  configuration: 'mobile'
                }, () => {

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        console.log('show devtool');

                    },  5000)
                })
            })
```

The api chrome.debugger works fine, but when...

```
webview.showDevTools(true)
```

The Webview touch mode just failed.

"chrome.debugger" conflict with "showDevTools(true)"

How set the webview to touch mode in NW.js

Comment: which NW.js version are you using? Chrome debugger doesn't support multiple clients until recently: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/devtools-release-notes#multi-client. If you are using NW 0.27 (chrome 63), please submit a bug report.

Comment: My NW.js version is 0.20.0
chrome.debugger works fine without webview.showDevTools(true)
But, failed when call the webview.showDevTools(true)

Comment: The failure is expected because devtools didn't support multi-client in NW 0.20

Comment: I have try update to NW.js version 0.27.4
The webview.showDevTools(true, container) notwork.  
The chrome.debugger.sendCommand 'Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled' notwork too
should i submit a bug report on github ?
T_T

Comment: Please use a new build, see https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/6374